# How do I add a description to a field in "GraphQL schema language"

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I have a graphql schema, a fragment of which looks like this:

```
type User {
    username: String!
    password: String!
}
```

In graphiql, there is a description field, but it always says "self-descriptive". How do I add descriptions to the schema?

Comment: PS hash your passwords kids!

Answer (score 167, accepted):

If you're using GraphQL.js version 0.7.0 or above, you can simply add a comment directly before the field, type, or argument you want to describe. For example:

```
# A type that describes the user
type User {
     # The user's username, should be typed in the login field.
     username: String!
     # The user's password.
     password: String!
}
```

Below version 0.7.0 it is not possible to add descriptions inside the schema language.

UPDATE: since version **v0.12.3** you should use **string literals**

```
"""
A type that describes the user. Its description might not 
fit within the bounds of 80 width and so you want MULTILINE
"""
type User {
     "The user's username, should be typed in the login field."
     username: String!
     "The user's password."
     password: String!

}
```

Comment: This is no longer the default, see: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/extendSchema.js#L47 -- should be a string literal like `"My description"`

Comment: So string literals are the current default as of February 2018.

Comment: Relevant part of spec: https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Descriptions

Comment: If anybody is looking for how to do it in TypeGraphQL, just use the `description` property in decorator options. eg. `@ObjectType({description:'Here'})`. Same for `@Field({description:...}, @Arg and @Query`

Answer (score 18):

This is a great question! And actually has a great history in `graphql` world.

There were multiple issues, discussions, and Pull Requests on the `graphql-js` repo that tried to discuss possible syntax for this, as it was something that a lot of members of the community felt were needed. Thanks to Lee Byron and [this Pull Request](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/464), we can actually add descriptions to a schema language by using traditional comments.

For example,

```
// Grab some helpers from the `graphql` project
const { buildSchema, graphql } = require('graphql');

// Build up our initial schema
const schema = buildSchema(`
schema {
  query: Query
}

# The Root Query type
type Query {
  user: User
}

# This is a User in our project
type User {
  # This is a user's name
  name: String!

  # This is a user's password
  password: String!
}
`);
```

And, if we're using `graphql` that's newer than `0.7.0`, the comments are actually turned into the description for the fields or types. We can verify this by running an introspection query on our schema:

```
const query = `
{
  __schema {
    types {
        name
        description,
        fields {
            name
            description
        }
    }
  }
}
`;

graphql(schema, query)
  .then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Which would give us a result that looks like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__schema": {
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "User",
          "description": "This is a User in our project",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "name",
              "description": "This is a user's name"
            },
            {
              "name": "password",
              "description": "This is a user's password"
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And shows us that the `#` comments were incorporated as the descriptions for the fields/comments that we put them on.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Very helpful thanks - I did search for a long time for an answer, and was struggling through lots of old issues - when the answer was so simple! :)

Comment: Yes, took me a while to find as well.  TYVM!

Comment: I'm using graphql 0.12.3 and this isn't working for me. Description is always null using the code above.

Answer (score 8):

In case you're using a **Java** implementation ....

For `graphql-java` version 7.0 (the latest version as of this writing) with a schema first approach, you can use **comments** above the field, type, or argument.

**String literals** are *not* valid syntax as of version 7.0.